# bsddb in Python and Unix

Tags: python, database, bsddb

I haven't heard of bsddb till recently.

http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/berkeley-db/index.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB

I haven't been able to figure out what exactly it is. bsddb seems to be installed on my Mac but I definitely didn't install it. Is that because bsddb comes installed by default? Is that true on all Unix machines? Is the library on my machine Oracle's distribution? (I tried which bsddb but that didn't work).

Could anyone just generally explain bsddb both in the the context of why it's in my machine and also in terms of the Python libraries provided (anydbm and bsddb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BDB is a database system available on Unix machines for probably two or more decades. It originally provided single-process database services (not at all like MySQL or PostgreSQL database *daemons* that provide services for other processes) so that applications could focus on their code and save everyone the hassle of writing and debugging hashed-access database code.

It was originally *very* simple system intended for a single-process-at-a-time key/value store, and intended to drastically speed up some operations that might have been done in simple plain text otherwise: the `/etc/master.passwd` that is probably on your OS X system (common to most? all? of the BSD systems) is a BDB version of the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` files  so that `login(1)` and `sshd(8)` and similar tools don't need to perform a *linear* search but instead use a hashed lookup to find the user account very quickly.

Newer versions of BDB integrate process-awareness, with full transactional support, and even SQL query support -- presumably to compete against [SQLite3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sqlite3), which has mostly supplanted BDB in *new* applications.

You can expect *some* form of BDB on nearly every Unix machine, but the versions available vary widely, so the features available may not be consistent. (On my Ubuntu system, I have BDB versions 4.7, 4.8, and 5.1 installed. Go figure.)

Comment: Ah great that helps my understanding a lot! Is the BDB on all machines the same on as the one released by Oracle? Or is it a vendor specific release...

Comment: It used to just be "Berkeley", then the original authors formed "SleepyCat Software" to do the database and nothing but the database, and back in 2006 Oracle acquired them because Oracle didn't already own enough databases.... It'll all be written by the same team of programmers and they've done a good job keeping previous applications running under newer versions of the library. Whether or not the one on _your_ system is from BSD or SleepyCat or from Oracle, I can't say. :)